# All user control instances should listen to a parent form event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have many user control instances in my parent form. Now when I click a button in the parent form, I want all user controls change in a similar way. Instead of looping through my user controls and telling each control what to do, I want every control to listen to an event in the parent form and do the change once the event in the parent form is raised.
Like traffic lights: When they go to green, every car starts. I dont have to tell every single driver to start driving.
Would this be possible?

Comment: I'm afraid you've already found the answer, just read the title again.

Comment: I have no clue how to technically do this. As I understand it, the user control has to listen to a main form event and so do the instances. Can you maybe provide a code snippet how to do that?

Comment: You don't need an event for that. All controls in a form are included in the Controls collection, see the code in the InitializeComponent function, you can see there how your controls are created, configured and appended to the controls collection. Based on that, you can simply iterate this collection and identify your "user controls" and do what ever you want to them when your button on the form is clicked

Comment: UserControl has a [ParentForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-containercontrol-parentform) property. When you get the parent form, you can get the button, then you can lisiten button's [OnClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) event.

Comment: *"When they go to green, every car starts"* - no, the **driver** starts the car. So, you need the driver

Answer (score 0):

.Net implements an *"Observer"* pattern via events and delegates.

```
// this is a Pseudocode
form.button.Click += DoSomething; // (object, EventArgs)

DoSomething(...)
{
    foreach(Control in form.controls)
    {
       // do whatever you need with your control
    }     
}
```

Now it is getting interesting. Lets say, you create custom buttons, textboxes; then you

```
public class CustomButton : Button.....
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox.....

// And in these ^^^ custom controls you can do this
override void ParentChanged(...)
{
    var form = this.FindForm();
    form.[SomeEvent] += Listen(.....); // (object, EventArgs)
    base.ParentChanged(...);
}

public void Listen(.....) // (object, EventArgs)
{
     // DO whatever you want with this control
     // for each control type will be different code
}
```

This second approach lets .Net Observer to do all the work but you need to do inheritance.

The first approach seem easier. Only you need to cover all control types in some `switch`. In the second approach each control type can do what it needs to itself.